# How can I post as guest again?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, user-accounts, unregistered-users

At the time where I didn't have a math.stackexchange account, I could ask questions as a guest. At mathoverflow, I can still ask questions as a guest. But if I click on "Ask question" at math.stackexchange, it says that I should log in. Thus my question is:

Is there somehow a way to be able to ask questions as a guest on math.stackexchange again? I tried deleting the cookies from my computer, but the problem was still there.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Yes, the community may disagree with the post's content, but that is surely not how downvotes should be used?

Comment: @Lovsovs: Voting is different on meta.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Really? I guess that could make sense. Do you have a link to a post that backs that up?

Comment: @Lovsovs: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta for example, has a section called "Voting is different on meta".

Comment: @AsafKaragila It says that *only* on posts tagged with **feature-request** does voting work as agreement/disagreement. I guess this question is actually about that, but then someone should edit the tags for the question.Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 10):

It is no longer possible to *ask* questions with an unregistered account on Mathematics Stack Exchange. The change was made on or about 10 Oct 2016, at least in part in because of the response to the feature request [Let's require registration to ask a question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/17244) (see [Grace Note's answer to that question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/25141)).

(Users can still *answer* questions without being registered.)